# Hiding a HTML element nested in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, attributes, refs

I have a table which is displayed as result from an API call to my backend from the front end via a form. The problem is the header is getting generated for each row of data, thus creating a redundancy.

I looked into `refs` as a way to access `HTML` elements.

```
    var BountyHunters = React.createClass({
       state : {toggleClass: true},
        getInitialState: function(){
          return({
            bountyHunters: []
          })
        },
        render: function () {
        var bountyHunters = this.state.bountyHunters
            bountyHunters = bountyHunters.map(function(bountyHunter, index){
             return (

              <tbody key={index}>
                <tr>
                  <td><span className={bountyHunter.obj.available}></span></td>
                  <td className="name">{bountyHunter.obj.name}</td>
                  <td className="rank">{bountyHunter.obj.rank}</td>
                  <td className="dist">{Math.floor(bountyHunter.dis /  1000)} km</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
             )
           })
            return(
              <div className="container">
                <div className="sixteen columns">
                  <div id="bountyhunter-container">
                    <form id="search" onSubmit= {this.handleSubmit}>
                      <label>Enter your latitude</label>
                      <input type="text" ref="lat" placeholder="latitude" requried/>
                      <label>Enter your longitude</label>
                      <input type="text" ref="lng" placeholder="longitude" requried/>
                      <input type="submit" className="button-primary" value="Find Bounty Hunters"/>
                    </form>
                    <table className="u-full-width">
                    <thead ref="thead">
                        <tr>
                          <th>Availability</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Bounties Claimed</th>
                          <th>Distance from you</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      {bountyHunters}
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            );
        },
        handleSubmit: function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var lng = this.refs.lng.value;
          var lat = this.refs.lat.value;
          this.refs.thead.style = 'block';

          fetch('/api/bountyHunters?lng=' + lng + '&lat=' + lat)
            .then(function(data){
              return data.json()
            }).then(json => {
              this.setState({
                 bountyHunters: json
              })
              console.log(json);
            });
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<BountyHunters/>, document.getElementById('bountyHunters'))
```

So you can see I created or used a `ref` attribute in the `<thead>` tag and then used it in the `handleSubmit` function

```
this.refs.thead.style.display = 'block';
```

I believe though this is having the effect of ripping all the other properties on the `thead` element and replacing them with just the `display: block` property and value.

So my question is this:
Is this the way you would go about doing this with refs?
I looked into many `add/remove` class methods specifically with react, as I know they're many DOM mounting lifecycle concerns one has to make. But was kinda surprised at all the hoops one would have to go through. 
Can someone guide me as what is the best/React—ish way to do this?

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzrM7.png)

**UPDATE**
I actually posted the code with my attempt to hide then show the display property of the `thead` tag.  The behavior I described was if the `thead` was returned in the `render` method.

Comment: It doesn't seem by your print nor code that the headers of the table are being generated for each row of the table; I can only see one header line in the print and the code looks alright. For the refs question, I'd suggest you'd consider adding a className attribute to the header and add custom CSS to add the style you desire, instead of using refs.

Comment: I updated my post to reflect what you mentioned! Thanks!